# Как в консоли .Net убрать из Trace лишние данные?

Tags: .net, логирование

Сейчас у меня в логе трейсера пишется вот такие данные: [image: Скриншот]
Я хотел бы их убрать. Не подскажете какую настройку в конфиге надо поправить?
Хочу логировать как идет отправка через SMTP, но что-то такой формат выдачи мне не нравится. Мне достаточно просто строки, что идет справа от таблицы.

Вот мой App.config:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true"></trace>   
<sources>
  <source name="System.Net" >
    <listeners>
      <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>

  <source name="System.Net.Sockets">
    <listeners>
      <add name="MyTraceFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>

<sharedListeners>
  <add
    name="MyTraceFile"
    type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
    initializeData="System.Net.trace.log"  
    traceOutputOptions="ProcessId, DateTime" />
</sharedListeners>

<switches>
  <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
  <add name="System.Net.Sockets" value="Verbose" />
</switches>
```

Comment: За вывод дампа данных отвечает [вот этот метод](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/Logging.cs,610ea3882b1e9b59). Строковое и hex представления выводятся вместе, оставить только строковое не получится, к сожалению.